# How to search for a particular word in a string from a arraylist of String

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a string

```
String string="I would loved to be the part of cricket team"
```

and I have a arraylist

```
ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList(); 
list.add("part");
list.add("bend");
list.add("bet");
list.add("bear");
list.add("beat");
list.add("become");
list.add("begin");
```

Now I want to search from this string using this arraylist. How can i Do that without using for loop ?

Comment: `Now I want to search from this string using this arraylist` Can you explain what it is ?

Comment: what you have tried so far.?

Comment: Means that if I search from this string using this arraylist then result should be "part".

Comment: You will need to iterate over the list somehow. Java 8 provides you with Streams and Lambda's, tried those yet?

Comment: try using string.contains(array[i]) and iterate over it and returnthe results..

Comment: @Stultuske- I wasn't aware of this Java8 feature, Let me try this

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 streams:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(s -> string.contains(s))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: @OnkarMusale Probably because none of the search strings matched the input.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check one by one by using `String.compare()` function.
Is it what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String x : list) {
    if(string.contains(x)) {
        System.out.print(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: `How can i Do that without using for loop ?`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko don't think so, it can be

Comment: @AndrewTobilko- I know we can use in this way also, but I was somehow trying to avoid that, that's why I asked this question

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use JAVA 8 feature 
String str = "I would loved to be the part of cricket team";

ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList(); 
list.add("part");
list.add("bend");
list.add("bet");
list.add("bear");
list.add("beat");
list.add("become"); 
list.add("begin");

boolean anyMatch = list.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.contains(str));
```